# cmake error while running on a mounted directory

Tags: windows, linux, cmake, mount

I have issue running cmake on a package residing in a mounted folder. I have full permissions on this mounted folder.

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:50 (MESSAGE):
The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec/fast"

/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build

make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 0.38 s in the future

make[1]: Entering directory
`/home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

make[1]: Warning: File `CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/flags.make' has
modification time 0.35 s in the future

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
/home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

/usr/bin/gcc -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
/home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

cc1: error:
/home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c:
Value too large for defined data type

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory
`/home/X/win_tmp/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

make: *** [cmTryCompileExec/fast] Error 2


CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Cmake seems to run fine when I copy the package on to my linux filesystem.

Thanks,
Gudge

Comment: Those timestamps in the future look horrible; are you running a kernel with [this bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3775) fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85999), the error `Value too large for defined data type` has to do with `gcc` executing `stat()` on Samba-mounted file systems. The inode returned is apparently rather large for those file systems.

The solution is to ensure your mount command has `nounix,noserverino` in the options column (in `/etc/fstab` or equivalent).

See the [`mount.cifs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) man page for further details.

Comment: @gudge, as an aside, I'm not criticising you, at least not directly :-) But I found this with about four minutes of Google searching. Now admittedly, I've often been told that my Google-fu is strong but you really should spend some time searching first.
And, if you did search, my sincerest apologies. But, in that case, you should have told us that you searched unsuccessfully, and you wouldn't have to suffer the rants of some old codger who didn't get enough sleep last night :-)

Comment: I apologize. I did search but may I should have paid attention.

Answer (score 0):

This problem with mounted folders can also manifest itself with a failure for the cmake command "`file(GLOB VAR PATTERNS)`" to find anything.  In my case, the subsequent command "`add_library`" would end up with no source files and fail with the following error:

> You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library ... without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file.

I hope that by mentioning this here that it will cut the search time of others from 4 to 2 minutes.